# Calculating a time before 1970 (fails with negative seconds)

Tags: ruby, time

I am new in ruby,and when I learn the Time class in ruby(In fact I follow the VTC video) I found something I can not make ,I want to caculate the born year of one person according to his age,

for example,when a person tell his age is "20",then I should caculate his born year.

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name,:age,:year_born
    def initialize(name,age)
        @name=name
        @age=age
        @year_born=(Time.now - age*31556962).year
    end

    def days_alive
        @age*365
    end
end
```

In the following code everything works well except the

```
@year_born=(Time.now - age*31556962).year
```

I got an error when I try

```
Person.new("name",43).year_born
```

which says:

```
ArgumentError: time must be positive
    ./person.rb:6:in `-'
    ./person.rb:6:in `initialize'
```

I know Time.now will return the seconds from 1970,that's to say

```
(2011-1970)<43
```

So the `Time.now-43*31556962` return a invalid value,but I want to know how to implement my requirement?

Comment: One general comment. It is impossible to tell one's born year just by the age at a certain time. You need further information (born month, day, even upto seconds in the worst case) to do that.

Comment: :) Thanks for your attention. In fact,it is not a real application,it is just a example in the tutorial.

Comment: I see. Good that you would not be in trouble with that. (But that should be a mistake in the tutorial.)

Comment: I think so. BTW,any Experience using scite in win system?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I use mostly linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Programming Ruby:

> `Time` is an abstraction of dates and
>   times. `Time` is stored internally as
>   the number of seconds and microseconds
>   since the epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00
>   UTC. On ***some*** operating systems, this
>   offset is allowed to be negative. Also
>   see the Date library module on page
>   742. (emphasis mine)

Which implies that on some operating systems, the offset is *not* allowed to be negative. So any of us elderly folks who were born before 1970 may blow up your code. Also keep in mind you're actually calculating `number_of_seconds_per_year * age_in_years`, which won't be very accurate.

Comment: "on some operating systems, the offset is not allowed to be negative" +100.   So that's to say the method of Time - is not safe?

Comment: Correct, in the sense that you may get an exception if subtracting the offset results in a time prior to the epoch, depending on the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

why not do it like this:

note that i am using

> (Time.now.year - age)

and that i have year_born as a method.

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name,:age
    def initialize(name,age)
        @name=name
        @age=age
    end

    def year_born
      (Time.now.year - age)
    end

    def days_alive
        @age*365
    end
end
```

However do not store the age in your DB(if you are going to save this in your DB). Just save the birth date.

Comment: Thanks,this works,but I want to know why Time.now-seconds does not work?

Comment: It does work.. see the docs http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/frames

Try `p Time.now; p Time.now-10`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using `Time`, but should be using either `Date` or `DateTime`, which have a greater range. `Date` doesn't know about times, which might fit your application better since you want day granularity.

```
require 'date'
Date.today - 20 * 365 # => #<Date: 1991-05-07 (4896767/2,0,2299161)>
Date.today - 50 * 365 # => #<Date: 1961-05-14 (4874867/2,0,2299161)>
(Date.today - 50 * 365).year # => 1961
```